# Cannot declare class ComposerAutoloaderInit

Tags: php, protocol-buffers

I have a question i have an error im not enabled to fix. The error is saying the name is already in use.
What im trying to do is im calling a API that needs to give some response back. Because of this error im not enabled to acces the data of my API

The Error

```
Cannot declare class ComposerAutoloaderInitd1e500cc63b56a87596c43fefa8d9495, because the name is already in use in
```

This is my autoload.php

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInitd1e500cc63b56a87596c43fefa8d9495::getLoader();
```

autoload_real.php

```
<?php

// autoload_real.php @generated by Composer

class ComposerAutoloaderInitd1e500cc63b56a87596c43fefa8d9495
{
    private static $loader;

    public static function loadClassLoader($class)
    {
        if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
            require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
        }
    }

    public static function getLoader()
    {
        if (null !== self::$loader) {
            return self::$loader;
        }

        spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInitd1e500cc63b56a87596c43fefa8d9495', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
        self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
        spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInitd1e500cc63b56a87596c43fefa8d9495', 'loadClassLoader'));

        $includePaths = require __DIR__ . '/include_paths.php';
        $includePaths[] = get_include_path();
        set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $includePaths));

        $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';

            call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInitd1e500cc63b56a87596c43fefa8d9495::getInitializer($loader));
        } else {
            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->set($namespace, $path);
            }

            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
            }

            $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
            if ($classMap) {
                $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
            }
        }

        $loader->register(true);

        return $loader;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get it to work? If yes - how.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when including two composer autoloaders from two directories where one originated as a copy of the other one (don't ask me why).

Based on this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/wp-media/wp-rocket/issues/1199) I concluded my solution:

Delete the composer lock-file (e.g. composer.lock) and execute `composer update`.

In my case I just deleted the vendor-directory too.

Comment: In my case I tried to use it in two places: my child theme, and my custom plugin. When I copied the vendor folder from the child theme to the plugin folder, the error occurred. It wasn't enough to composer a fresh vendor folder in the new project, I deleted vendor and re-composed in the original child theme folder. Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You probably ran `composer install` in a subdirectory. i had the same error, because there was a second `vendor` directory somewhere in my project.

Remove all `vendor` directories and then run `composer clear-cache` and `composer install`.

Now the error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my VPS and it worked.

I tried everything. Nothing had worked.

1. I tried "compose update", not working.
2. I tried restore the whole website from its backup, not working.
3. I removed autoloader line from my .php file, not working.
4. The strange part is that I copied the same file to another name, it worked.
5. Of course I tried systemctl restart nginx many many times.

I almost want to kill myself and out of despair, I restarted my VPS... Magic happened. Everything was back to normal.

Comment: I had this issue and like in Your case, restart make's magic. Why? I really want to know ;)

Comment: I don't know. I am happy that the magic works for you too!